# In JavaScript What is the order of Output for this input and WHY?

Tags: javascript

Why is the Output first, third and second??

```js
console.log("first");
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('second');
}, 0);
console.log('third');
```

Comment: because `second` is coming from an async process

Comment: to add @MisterJojo, you can see [this video](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=770) it explains the javascript event loop and everything related to it.

Comment: Because `setTimeout` callback is put in a queue. Queued jobs will only execute when the current script has finished executing, and the call stack is empty.